# Eclipse Mylyn Jira integration: Is there a way to synchronize queries for a filter with updated search parameters?

Tags: eclipse, jira, mylyn

I use Eclipse Mars 4.5.2 with Jira 6.3.14 and Mylyn 3.18. In Jira my company has a custom filter which shows the currently active sprint, through filtering for the fix version of "sprint_###" where ### is the current sprint. In Eclipse, in my Task List, I have a query which retrieves this filter, after which I can use this for context switching.

Every time we start a new sprint, we change the current_sprint filter to filter for the new sprint, for example from 079 to 080. However, this doesn't update the filter definition inside my Task List, which means that the task list still points to the previous filter definition, and thus to the previous sprint. I need to manually recreate the filter each time we start a new sprint. This also means that I have to delete the old filter, which then throws all those issues into the Unmatched folder where I need to delete them from the list as well.

How can I avoid having to manually recreate this filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By chance I stumbled across this solution:

1. Right click on the query in the task list and choose "Properties";
2. Click the "Update from Repository" button;
3. Click "finish".

The filter repository definition is now updated and queries the server again using the new filter.